# Gulp watch is not working while saving sass file

Tags: gulp-watch

I am new to gulp and I want to activate gulp watcher feature so as to make changes in css file when saving scss file. I searched this issue a lot and tried all solutions but none of them worked. I'll be glad if anyone helped me with this problem. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
gulp.task("hello", function() {
  console.log("Hello Zell");
});
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
gulp.task("sass", function() {
  return gulp
    .src("scss/login360.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("styles"));
});
gulp.task("watch", function() {
  gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ["watch"]);
});
```

Comment: This line won't work with gulp4 - you probably saw that in an old gulp3-based tutorial: `gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ["watch"]);`.  If you search for your error message you will find you need to change that to: `gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", gulp.series"watch"));`

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am using gulp 3.9.0 not 4